# Hyper-V is enabled, but still unable to install HAXM

Tags: android-studio, windows-8.1, haxm

I have windows 8.1 enterprise, and Hyper-V is also enabled.

[image]

But I still get the following error while trying to install HAXM for android studio:

[image]

Please tell me how to resolve this

Comment: check if virtualizaion is enabled on bios

Comment: @Aman Hyper-V appears even if virtualization is disabled in BIOS?

Comment: I checked my BIOS settings and virtualization is already enabled.

Comment: i think you should go through this article.. specially troubleshooting area. https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Comment: Haxm depends on VT-x or VT-d. Having hyper-v enabled will only create problems. In some cases, antivirus softwares creates problems with HAXM. Do you have avast ? If so, it has a virtualization protection option, disable that. The name should be "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization". Disable this.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V and HAXM are incompatible.  You cannot have both active at the same time.  See the docs at the full haxm install from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager .